# What is the most effective way to make unzipped copy of a gzipped file on GCS?

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

We have a lot of gzipped files on our gcs. To speed up out dataflow job we would like to make an unzipped copy of the files, dataflow `TextIO` isn't that fast with zipped files.

I'm trying to figure out what the most effective way is to make an unzipped copy of the file on gcs.

As a start I thought I would just start to write a simple download program, but I fail to get the same performance as `gsutil` have.

So accepted answers to this question would be an example of how to make a super, hopefully simple, download of files from gcs, or how to copy and unzip on the fly on gcs.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement an App Engine or Compute Engine application that processes [object change notifications](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification) from GCS, so it discovers newly uploaded gzip files and reads/writes the corresponding unzipped file into GCS. This would probably be faster than downloading to your corporate network and reuploading (depending on the speed of your Internet connection).

Comment: That is probably the long term plan for us, but not as easy to squeeze in in the current process. I plan to solve it in the dataflow job somehow.